# Весь контент уезжает вверх при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, css-animation

При обновлении страницы весь контент уезжает вверх, что только не пробовал, и функцию preload вписывал, и задавал высоту и ширину контента(вроде бы) В CSS пока что уровень "метод тыка", так что сильно не удивляйтесь бессмысленным параметрам и т.д. В целом, из-за чего это может быть?
Можете посмотреть через средства разработчиков в браузере, или же могу скинуть полный код.
UPD: контент едет в Microsoft Edge

[Сайт на фри хосте](https://flashnftclub.000webhostapp.com/)

Comment: Какой контент уезжает? У меня вроде все на месте остается при обновлении страницы. Или ни туда смотрю?

Comment: @edosjoy кажется у меня получилось исправить, правда запуск сайта с хоста показывает другое

Comment: @edosjoy Добавил ответ на свой же вопрос. Было бы очень круто, если бы вы уточнили мне, в чём была причина? Размер страницы не соответствовал размеру контейнера с контентом, поэтому при обновлении оно всё уезжало вверх?  Могу откатить изменения для наглядности

Comment: @edosjoy UDP: в браузере Edge такая тема, в опере все нормально

Answer (score 1):

Добавил div для контента, внутрь которого запихнул все остальные div'ы.
И изменил

```
 html {
  height: 100%;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

на

```
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%);
  overflow: hidden;
}
#content{
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```